# Import a user defined checkstyle eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, checkstyle

I have a user defined checkstyle xml file and jar file. How can I import the xml and jar file in eclipse.

Should I install eclipse checkstyle plugin and then import my user defined check style in it or is there any alternate way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by *user defined checkstyle*, you mean you created some new rules and want them to be a part of your checkstyle, then you can do it like following :

1. Create **plugin project** and add your **custom checks** there.
2. Make appropriate changes to **plugin.xml**, **checkstyle_packages.xml.**
3. Export the project as **Deployable Plug-ins and fragments**  (*Export > Plug-in Developement*)
4. Copy the jar file to *Eclipse Plugin* folde, so *no need to install your custom check* .

You can refer [this tutorial](http://eclipse-cs.sourceforge.net/extending.html)

Comment: The tutorial returns 404

Comment: I think this is the correct link: https://checkstyle.org/eclipse-cs/#!/custom-checks

Answer (score 4):

Go to Preferences -> Checkstyle. In the Global Check Configurations box you can specify your own files.

Comment: How can I verify if my user defined check list is used other then default one.

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse inbuilt checkstyle will not be available,so first you need to install the plugin.

I found this helpful

https://code.google.com/p/instinct/wiki/ConfiguringCheckstyleForEclipse